# epochs = mne.Epochs(raw, events, tmin=-0.5, tmax=25, event_id=event_dict, preload=True) what is the exact meaning of this code

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, data-preprocessing, mne-python

epochs = mne.Epochs(raw, events, tmin=-0.5, tmax=25, event_id=event_dict,
preload=True)what is the exact meaning of this code in mne library. what  if I change the value of tmin. and tmax

about a line of code of mne library I.e. epochs = mne.Epochs(raw, events, tmin=-0.5, tmax=25, event_id=event_dict,
preload=True)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The line is making fixed time windows around your events/stimuli. The time window you have created is to include -0.5 sec, before the onset of stimuli, and 25 second after. You can change this time according to your specific requirements.
The default is tmin -0.5 and tmax = 0.5.